# set::find() not working with user define data type

Tags: c++, stdset

When I am searching for a key which is not present in my set then find() instead of returning iterator to end is returning  an iterator to an another object which is not equal to key but present in set.

I have no idea whats going wrong.

**CODE**

```
class node{
public:
    int a, b;
    node(int a, int b):a(a), b(b){}

    bool operator>(const node &ob)const{
        return (this->b - this->a) > (ob.b - ob.a);     
    }

    bool operator==(const node &ob)const{
        return ((this->a == ob.a) && (this->b == ob.b));
    }
};

void print(set<node,greater<node>> &s){
    cout << "[ ";
    for(const node &ob: s){
        cout << "(" << ob.a << "," << ob.b << ") ";
    }

    cout <<"]\n--------------------------------" << endl;
}
set<node,greater<node>> s;                  
int main(){
    s.insert(node(0,3));
    s.insert(node(3,8));
    print(s);
    s.erase(node(3,8));
    cout << "After erasing (3, 8)" << endl;
    print(s);
    cout << "Searching for key (3,6)" << endl;
    set<node,greater<node>>::iterator i = s.find(node(3,6));
    if(i == s.end()){
        cout << "Not Found" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Found : " << "(" << i->a << "," << i->b << ")" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
[ (3,8) (0,3) ]
--------------------------------
After erasing (3, 8)
[ (0,3) ]
--------------------------------
Searching for key (3,6)
Found : (0,3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing objects as equal or not [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) uses the comparison function (i.e. `greater<node>` which uses `node::operator>`) but not `node::operator==` (as you expected).

> In imprecise terms, two objects `a` and `b` are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

For `node(3,6)` and `node(0,3)`, both `operator> (node(3,6),  node(0,3))` and `operator> (node(0,3),  node(3,6))` return `false`, then they're considered equivalent.

Comment: Oh! so that means all the values having same difference will consider to be same(in my case)?

Comment: @AshutoshAswal Yes, exactly.